# How can I embed my Wordpress.org blog in an ASP.NET MVC View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, wordpress

I have a blog in Wordpress.org (and no intention to host it myself in the short term).

Please tell me if it is possible, and how, to dynamically embed (for showing/interacting, not storing content) that blog inside an ASP.NET MVC 3 View.

Thanks!

Comment: Besides using an iFrame, one thing I can think of off the top of my head would be to pull RSS feeds, parse them and display them on your MVC3 view pages using the same HTML and CSS as your  Wordpress pages.

You're pages would load slower though because it would need to pull the data on the fly, or you would need to store them in a separate database with a running process that pulls and stores the blog post data periodically.  This wouldn't help you with comments though, there is no way to tie those together.

Is there a particular reason why you want to do this?

Comment: Could use your rss/atom feed as a data source and style it/output it in your view

Comment: The reason is just available time. I will try that IFrame and RSS feed options. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use an `<iframe>` pointing to your WordPresss blog.